# Is there a way of getting a class to "see" variables in the main script? (Sort of `set` but not using `set`)

Tags: php, variables, scope, attributes

This is one of those situations where I do not know how to ask the question. I have looked here and elsewhere and found no joy. If this is a duplicate question I would be grateful for a pointer and will delete this.

I am building a little site that will never get more than 10 visitors a day so code execution efficiency is not an issue. My productivity is. I am a clumsy programmer so have automated everything I can via a Utility `trait`. This has eliminated huge number of typos, allowed for cleaner code in general and kept `classes` clean. (And it saves a lot of boring rote coding.)

I know professionals will not approve but I have to make progress with the level of knowledge I have plus the bit I learn every day.

By rigidly enforcing common naming all over the place the `trait` does all Create, Update, Read and Delete (`CRUD`) operations plus all `gets` and `sets` etc. I have hit a problem with updates tho.

All the values I want are in local `$normalVariable` or `POST` form.

Obviously I can do myriad individual `sets` but that's a lot of work and a lot of errors.

```
function loadObject($theObject)
{
  $list = $theObject->doGet("classAttributesLong");// a listing of all atributes
  foreach ($list as $item)
  {
    global $$item;
    $local = $$item;
    if (isset($local))
    {
      $theObject->doSet("$item", $local);
    }
  }
}
```

I have done this local `function` that does the job. I can include it where needed but that is untidy. Is there any way of getting this functionality into a `class\trait`?

The `trait` uses the name of the `class'` `attributes` to perform many functions. PHP variables, tables, columns, `POST` variables etc all use the same names and, with some case changing, it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, but your question (and general scenario) is not clear at all. Can you please try rephrasing it?

Comment: OK will do so later. Will delete this shortly and represent. I have a "solution" but it could be better. Thanks for trying anyway.